# Live USB hangs after selecting GRUB menu entry -- new PC

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I know there are several dozen threads on this website already about GRUB issues of a similar nature, but I've looked at a fair few and am yet to find a solution that works for this particular issue.

I just finished assembling a new PC and want to put Ubuntu on it. I flashed Ubuntu Budgie to a USB stick -- note, I don't have amazing faith in it as I just found it and it's several years old & missing the casing.

If I simply select any of the options it goes to a black screen indefinitely. If I change some of the parameters by pressing `e` and then `F10` it will say "Booting a command list" and then freeze with a cursor underneath that. I have tried changing a few options, like adding `nomodeset` and `radeon.modeset=0` in place of `quiet splash` but it all produces the same thing. I've also tried fiddling with the BIOS settings to no end (mainly enabling/disabling CSM), although I did make extra sure that Secure Boot was disabled.

<s>I do think it's something to do with the graphics -- I remember a number of years ago Debian was giving me tremendous grief about my AMD card, and this install is being done on an R9 390 GPU since my new processor doesn't have an iGPU.</s> Nevermind, I just tried an Arch live USB which would be all terminal-based and that presents the same issue. I'm leaning towards the USB being faulty.

It's quite irritating as I can't even get an error dump to troubleshoot, and nothing seems to be working. I'm kind of at my wit's end and I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight and assistance.

Comment: Post a screenshot , also disable quiet and splash in grub command line , also what is your pc config?

Comment: Not much need for a picture, it's either totally blank for just selecting the menu entry or if I change the parameters it's just "Booting a command list" even with quiet splash disabled

Comment: PC specs are:

Ryzen 7 5800x /
R9 390 /
32GB RAM (3600MHz)

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem and already tried different usb drives and flash methods.

Comment: @MatF I updated the BIOS and I believe that fixed it